# How to center text and a subline in a list item?

Tags: html, css

I had a list that was structured like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I wanted each of my list items to have a height of 50px, so I set the line-height of `<a>` to 50px and it worked fine.

However, now I'm trying to add a sub-line to each `<a>` tag so that it looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      Link
      <span class="sub-line">Link Info</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The sub-line would be a smaller font and would show up comfortably under the link text. I've been messing around with display and line-height and absolute positioning, but I've had no luck coming up with a clean solution. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the list horizonatal or vertical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
a {
    position: relative;
}

a span {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 0.5em;
    bottom: -1em;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M3jnU/2/)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I understand from your question:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4AsPZ/2/)**

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#">
    Link
    <sub>Link Info</sub>
</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
a     { text-decoration: none; }
a sub { font-size: 8px; }
li    { text-align: center; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `display: block` to put the sub line below the link text with a smaller font

```css
.sub-line {
    display: block;
    font-size: 80%;
}
```

To reduce the distance

```css
    line-height: 50%;
```

and to center both horizontally

```css
li {
    text-align: center;
}
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CA84X/)

Comment: If you add a bg-color to the `li` in your fiddle you can see that the anchor is not "contained" within the `li`. Some tweaking should take care of that though.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thank you for the hint, I didn't notice this. I played with the fiddle and increasing `line-height` fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://cssdeck.com/labs/m2x5iksq)

Try this:

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
a {
  line-height: 50px;
  display: block;
}
span {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1px;
  font-size: 75%;
  //Here you can play with negative margin-top for better positioning 
}
```